# Using of tenses!

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> This year two Spanish novelists (have been awarded) or (were awarded)

I have had an argument about this,
I have chosen *have been awarded* but my friend says that Nobel is once a year, that's why past simple is the more suitable one.

Comment: Some people find the intransitive use of "awarded" to be in poor taste.

Comment: 'Rules' about when to use the past simple rather than the present perfect are almost invariably inadequate. Like most other rules in English.

Comment: When either is OK, as here, use the shorter one. That's what native speakers do. You generally hafta have a special circumstance to use a longer one.

Comment: Use whichever one will make your critic the most tense.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly a matter of what intention you have. If you want to give this information as news to someone you use present perfect. If you see the information as something in the past you use past tense. So the choice of tense is not so much a grammar thing but a matter of your personal attitude and the situation when and where you say or write this.

Comment: Ok, but what about time expression "this year" then?

Comment: Even when something happened this year the event can be news for someone and you want to tell it as news or it can be seen by you as a past event that happened earlier this year.

Answer (score 0):

In general, use the present perfect when the exact date is unknown or unimportant, or you are counting recurrences. Otherwise simple past should be fine. But who speaks completely grammatically?